# KonvaJS rotate on touch devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, konvajs, hammer

can you assist me?

https://konvajs.github.io/docs/sandbox/Multi-touch_Scale_Stage.html

this tutorial works perfectly, can you help me please make the rotation in same manner? i want to rotate my stage clockwise and counterclockwise.

Answer (score 0):

This simplest way is to add gesture recognition library and then use `rotate` event.

For example, I added https://zingchart.github.io/zingtouch/ library.

```
var containerElement = document.getElementById('container');
var activeRegion = ZingTouch.Region(containerElement);

var childElement = document.getElementById('container');
activeRegion.bind(childElement, 'rotate', function(event){
    stage.rotation(-event.detail.angle);
    stage.draw();
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/lavrton/7nLte356/9/

Comment: thank you, but just checked your example on ipad/iphone - black square just dragging, no rotation